# _REQUEST only returning the first letter of input

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to update records in a database through a form (post), but when I access the global parameter variables, only the first character of the original input is returned for some reason.

```
      $conn->beginTransaction();
      $sql = "UPDATE AS_PEOPLE SET pid=? WHERE name=?";
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

      $values = Array($_REQUEST['project'][0], $_REQUEST['person'][0]);

      $stmt->execute($values);
      $conn->commit();

      echo "Ressource allocated<br>";
      print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here

```
$values = Array($_REQUEST['project'][0], $_REQUEST['person'][0]);
```

`$_REQUEST['project']` and `$_REQUEST['person']` are strings, containing values of selected option. If you tell php to get the `index` of `0` of a string it returns the first letter only

```
   $values = Array($_REQUEST['project'], $_REQUEST['person']);
```